# What is the best way to handle CS8602 "may be null here" warnings which are not accurate?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, nullable-reference-types

[MRE on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xnSvTV)

In the following example, I get warning CS8602 in method `Print()`. I am unsure why because it seem to me static analysis would show that `Print` is only ever called after `Prepare` - and as it's a private method it can't be called any other way, therefore `o`would always be non-null when accessed.

I've been impressed how clever the compiler is at telling when a nullable reference variable is definitely not null even in quite complex code logic so is this a limitation in the compiler or a misunderstanding on my part?

What should I do about it? Suppressing the warning seems like a code smell to me, but testing for null seems like paranoid coding.

```
using System;

#nullable enable
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var p = new Program();
        p.Go();
    }
    
    object? o;
    public void Go()
    {
        Prepare();
        Print();
    }
    
    private void Prepare()
    {
        o = "Test String";
    }
    private void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()); //dereference of a possibly null reference
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know for sure that it's not going to be `null`, use `o!.ToString()`

Comment: Or else do a check:   if (o!=null) Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko perhaps it's as simple as that... though I am starting to find all these special operators make for somewhat ugly code and are they themselves a bit of a code-smell?

Comment: Well, the compiler can't guarantee that `Prepare` will always be called before `Print`, hence it does not know that `o` is non-null, so it warns you. You can use null-conditional, too - i.e. `o?.ToString()`. Ideally, `o` should be set in the constructor, in which case it could be made non-nullable. This would require significant refactoring, though, and may not always be possible.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko why can't it guarantee that? The compiler can see exactly where it is called. Of course I might later write another method that doesn't guarantee non-nullnes but in the MRE, surely it _is_guaranteed?

Comment: You're right: the compiler *could* perform cross-method static analysis to analyze every possible call sequence and derive nullability from that -- it just doesn't, because such a thing is both costly, hard to get right and usually doesn't lead to more robust code. As you've pointed out, a single new method could suddenly end up producing warnings in a completely different method, in a way that may not at all be obvious to the programmer.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - I wasn't sure where it does draw the line, as I said it's impressive what it _can_ do. Is there any good documentation what it does/doesn't check or how the analysis works?

Comment: Basically, it's basic: it won't hop across methods to check at all, but you can use [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) to annotate methods and tell the compiler what effects the method will have. *Within* methods, it's pretty smart -- once you've checked for `null` once (implicity or explicitly), it knows at what places a new check is not necessary.

Comment: In this particular case, an attribute would not help -- the arguably "right" fix would be to ensure your object can't be in a partially initialized state, by moving things to the constructor, or using things like `Lazy<T>` or an inner class to handle the partial initialization in a robust way (or rearranging methods, of course).

Comment: @Mr.Boy The compiler can see where it's called in your program. However, it must consider possible usages of your class via reflection, which lets you ignore `private` qualifiers and jump right into `Print` without a `Prepare`.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko: that's not really an argument in this case, since nullable warnings only occur at compile time and are only ever advisory. Reflection can be used to violate all manner of assumptions that would make static analysis pointless. For example, you can also use reflection to set any field declared as non-nullable to `null` without any kind of override, but obviously the compiler has to assume you don't do that, otherwise NRTs become useless altogether.

Comment: @JeroenMostert While I agree that both a call of a private method and a setting of a non-nullable field to null via reflection are violations, somehow the former sounds more like an infraction, while the later sounds more like an aggravated felony to me :-)